# using videoview to play video with audio file

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

My goal is to play a video file (which has audio as well) on the click of a button; But somehow, just the video displays but there is no audio.

**My MainActivity.java:**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    VideoView mVideoView=(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
  //mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.play_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            String uriPath="android.resource://com.example.android.happybirthday/"+R.raw.video_2;
            VideoView mVideoView=(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
            Uri uri =Uri.parse(uriPath);
            mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
            mVideoView.requestFocus();
            mVideoView.start();
            mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(MainActivity.this));
            mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.setVolume(0,0);
                }
            });
        }
    }); 
 }
```

**My activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.android.happybirthday.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:text="Play"
    android:id="@+id/play_button"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set volume of media player. You can do by first setting listener `videoView.setOnPreparedListener(preparedListener);` and then you can in method `public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer m) {` of `preparedListener` set desired volume `m.setVolume(0f, 0f);`

Example with inline listener:

```
videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.setVolume(0, 0);
    }
});
```